# How can I open/run 2 projects in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

I'd like to know how can I open B project in presence of A project. I'm a windows user having intellij ultimate. I know the possibility to create the B project as module while A project already opened but need to know if I can bring B project/module (with A) that is already created. Also how can I run to module simultaneously.  This is for microservice purpose

Comment: You can use File | Project Structure | Modules | + | Import Module. See also https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-managing-modules.html#import-module .

Comment: use two workspace.import project and run in two different workspace with different port

Answer (score 1):

[image]

1. From file menu choose Project structure
2. Go to Modules under project settings
3. Press"+" & give the path where the module lies
4. Press Ok - est voilà